# ls -l | cut -c1-11,50- Can Someone Explain the 2nd part after the pipe?

Tags: linux, command-line, cut, options

I have taken a course in that suddenly I saw this, I understood until the pipe but the options used after the pipe for the command cut are bit confusing

Comment: Relevant: [Why **not** parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/126755)

Comment: Please try to write questions so that the question text itself is complete even without the title. It's a common practice and a good idea for at least two reasons: some readers automatically skip titles and read the question, which would lead to confusion here, since the actual pipe isn't in the question; and also it's easier to copy the code from the question text if necessary, since the title is a link, while the main text is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-c` [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) selects only specified characters or ranges of characters separated by comas:

```
N      N'th byte, character or field, counted from 1

N-     from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line

N-M    from N'th to M'th (included) byte, character or field

-M     from first to M'th (included) byte, character or field
```

so `cut -c1-11,50-` will print characters 1 to 11 and 50 to end of line from every line printed by `ls -l`.

So you will get the file permissions (first 11 characters) and the rest depends on length of your username, size of the files etc., but I assume the idea might be to print name of the file (using `cut -f` might be better if this was the goal, but generally [parsing ls is not a good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead))?

Comment: With ast-open `ls`, you'd rather use `ls --format='%(mode)s %(name)s`, or `ls --format='%(mode)s %(name)s%(linkop:case:?*: %(linkop)s %(linkpath)s:)s'` to also get the `-> target` for symlinks.

Comment: See also `stat -Lns +mode -- *` with `zsh`'s `stat` or `find ./* -prune -printf '%M %f\n'` with GNU `find` or `stat -c '%A %n' -- *` with GNU stat.